# I want to link to my homepage: ./ or /?

Tags: html, anchor

If I want to link to my homepage, which should point to the root folder, is there a difference between:

`<a href="./">` and `<a href="/">`

Or is there any 'industry recommended' practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./` points to the current directory. `/` points to the root directory.

Comment: For completeness, note that `../` points to the directory one 'above' the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `/`. `./` means "from the current position in the path", so if you're located in *http://www.example.com/some/subdir* and your link points to *./somepage.html* the link will lead to *http://www.example.com/some/subdir/somepage.html*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a big difference between the two things - depending on the place from where you link.

If you are in `/page.htm`, there is no real difference, but if you are in `/folder/page.htm` then the first one refers to `/folder/` which is probably not what you want to achieve whereas the second one is the one to go for.